# Apex Trigger: After Update - need to update fields as part of query

Tags: apex, trigger

I'm trying to make an email send to all contacts that are on an account related to a contract. To trigger it, I thought I'd have a field update on the record using time-delay workflows, and then the trigger clear the field so the email only ever sends once, not every time the record is edited.

I can't quite figure out how to do this logically.

This is what I have so far:

```
trigger NPSEmail on Contract (after update) {

    // you need to insert a check to capture the change is the custom field here
    System.debug('++++ NPSemail Trigger Starts' );

    Contract NowNPSDate = [SELECT SendNPS__c FROM Contract where Id=: trigger.new[0].id];

    System.debug('++++ NPSemail Current Email Date' );
    System.debug(NowNPSDate);

    if(NowNPSDate.SendNPS__C == Date.today()){
        Contract cont = [SELECT AccountId FROM Contract where Id= :trigger.new[0].id]; //get the ACCOUNT from Contract
        List<Contact> contacts = [Select Id From Contact Where AccountID =:cont.AccountId]; // Get Contact list related to ACCOUNT
        List<Id> conIds = new List<Id>();

        for(Contact c: contacts) {
            conIds.add(c.Id); 
            System.debug('++++ Email Ids' );        
            System.debug(conIds);
        }

        Messaging.MassEmailMessage email = new Messaging.MassEmailMessage(); 
        email.setTargetObjectIds(conIds);
        email.setTemplateId('00X19000000DdQK');
        Messaging.SendEmail(New Messaging.MassEmailMessage[] {email});
    }

    for (Contract obj: trigger.new){
        obj.SendNPS__c = null; 
    }
}
```

If I run that, the bit at the end which nulls the date causes an error. I believe it is due to field updates would cause an infinite loop on After Update.

Can anyone think of a way around this quandary?

I have Process Builder, although I don't think that helps in this instance.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how the trigger might look written so that it handles the case where there are multiple Contracts updated at once (bulkified);

```
trigger NPSEmail on Contract (before update) {
    Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>();
    for (Contract c : Trigger.new) {
        if (c.SendNPS__C == Date.today()) {
            if (c.AccountId != null) {
                accountIds.add(c.AccountId);
            }
            c.SendNPS__C = null;
        }
    }
    if (accountIds.size() > 0) {
        Map<Id, Contact> contacts = new Map<Id, Contact>([
                select Id
                from Contact
                where AccountId in :accountIds
                and Email != null
                ]);
        Messaging.MassEmailMessage email = new Messaging.MassEmailMessage(); 
        email.setTargetObjectIds(contacts.keySet());
        email.setTemplateId('00X19000000DdQK');
        Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.MassEmailMessage[] {emails});
    }
}
```

There is no need to re-query: all the fields of the Contract are automatically populated. And in "before" triggers you can modify the values too because the trigger is running before the save to the database. (In "after" triggers that is not allowed as you have discovered.) You can side-step the need to loop to gather IDs by making use of this [convenient map constructor](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_map.htm#apex_System_Map_ctor).